# pass view result from one view to another

Tags: 7, views

I have a view that outputs field content, and outputs one result.  There are four additional views that I need to have this result passed to somehow so I can filter the nid of that result out of the possible results for the other four views.

It's the end of the day so I wrote this question in haste, if it is no clear, please ask for clarification.  I will review later and update if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Views field view module ,https://drupal.org/project/views_field_view
with which you can have a view inside a view,and pass an argument from one view to another.

Answer (score 0):

You might try [Views Filter View](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/dereine/1443726) or [Other View Filter](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/bbinkovitz/2733827), two very similar modules that allow you to filter one view by the output of another.